# Selenium RC with safari issues - Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Executor has not been started yet

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-rc, safari-extension

I am trying to open safari using Selenium RC.
However, Safari instance is created and stays in Requesting connection mode
(SafariDriver requesting connection at ws://localhost:3078/wd).

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.safari
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url=>"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",    :desired_capabilities=>caps
```

above stuff hung up and fails with -
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Executor has not been started yet (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
    from [remote server] com.google.common.base.Preconditions(Preconditions.java):145:in `checkState'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java):123:in`execute'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):432:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):140:in`startSession'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):95:in `<init>'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver(SafariDriver.java):33:in`'
    from [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):-2:in `newInstance0'
    from [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):39:in`newInstance'
    from [remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java):27:in `newInstance'
    from [remote server] java.lang.reflect.Constructor(Constructor.java):513:in`newInstance'
    from [remote server] java.lang.Class(Class.java):355:in `newInstance0'
    from [remote server] java.lang.Class(Class.java):308:in`newInstance'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory(DefaultDriverFactory.java):61:in `callConstructor'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory(DefaultDriverFactory.java):52:in`newInstance'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator(DefaultSession.java):197:in `call'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator(DefaultSession.java):1:in`call'
... 4 levels...
    from [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):908:in `run'
    from [remote server] java.lang.Thread(Thread.java):680:in`run'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in`initialize'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in`create_response'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:59:in `request'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in`call'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:92:in`create_session'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in`new'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in `for'
    from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:65:in`for'
    from (irb):7

Comment: I'm having what looks like the same problem. Have you followed the directions on http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver ?

Comment: For me locking version of gem libwebsocket to 0.1.3 resolved this issue.Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I kept running into this problem when using Selenium Webdriver from Ruby. I solved it a couple times but the error came back. So I wrote my rspec tests to be loaded by jRuby on Windows and ran the Selenium calls in Java. Safari works now.